# Python Scrapy - Ajax Pagination Tripadvisor

Tags: python, ajax, pagination, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using Python-Scrapy to scrap the reviews of tripadvisor members pages. 
Here is the url I'm using : http://www.tripadvisor.com/members/scottca075

I'm able to get the first page using scrapy. I haven't been able to get the other pages. I observed the ***XHR*** Request in the **Network** Tab of the browser on clicking Next button.

One GET and One POST request is sent:
On checking the parameters for the GET request, I see this:

```
action : undefined_Other_ClickNext_REVIEWS_ALL
gaa : Other_ClickNext_REVIEWS_ALL
gal : 50
gams : 0
gapu : Vq85qQoQKjYAABktcRMAAAAh
gass : members`
```

The request url is

```
 `http://www.tripadvisor.com/ActionRecord?action=undefined_Other_ClickNext_REVIEWS_ALL&gaa=Other_ClickNext_REVIEWS_ALL&gal=0&gass=members&gapu=Vq8xPAoQLnMAAUutB9gAAAAJ&gams=1`
```

The parameter `gal` represents the offset. Each page has 50 reviews. On moving to the second page by clicking the next button, the parameter `gal` is set to `50`. Then, `100,150,200..`and so on.

The data that I want is in the POST request in json format. [Image of JSON data in POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8szKN.png). The request url on the post request is `http://www.tripadvisor.com/ModuleAjax?`

I'm confused as to how to make the request in scrapy to get the data.
I tried using `FormRequest` as follows:

```
pagination_url = "http://www.tripadvisor.com/ActionRecord"
form_date = {'action':'undefined_Other_ClickNext_REVIEWS_ALL','gaa':'Other_ClickNext_REVIEWS_ALL', 'gal':'0','gams':'0','gapu':'Vq8EngoQL3EAAJKgcx4AAAAN','gass':'members'}
FormRequest(url=self.pagination_url, formdata=formdata, callback=self.parseItem)
```

I also tried setting headers options in the FormRequest

```
headers = {'Host':'www.tripadvisor.com','Referer':'http://www.tripadvisor.com/members/prizm','X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
```

If someone could explain what I'm missing and point me in the right direction that would be great. I have run out of ideas.

And also, I'm aware that I can use selenium. But I want to know if there is a faster way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Use ScrapyJS - Scrapy+JavaScript integration

To use ScrapyJS in your project, you first need to enable the middleware:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapyjs.SplashMiddleware': 725,
}
```

For example, if we wanted to retrieve the rendered HTML for a page, we could do something like this:

```
    import scrapy

    class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    start_urls = ["http://example.com", "http://example.com/foo"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, meta={
                'splash': {
                    'endpoint': 'render.html',
                    'args': {'wait': 0.5}
                }
            })

    def parse(self, response):
        # response.body is a result of render.html call; it
        # contains HTML processed by a browser.
        # …
```

A common scenario is that the user needs to click a button before the page is displayed. We can handle this using jQuery with Splash:

```
function main(splash)
    splash:autoload("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js")
    splash:go("http://example.com")
    splash:runjs("$('#some-button').click()")
    return splash:html()
end
```

For more details [check here](http://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash/)

Answer (score 0):

so for you are doing correct,
add the yield in front of FormRequest as:

```
yield FormRequest(''')
```

secondly focus on the value of gal, because it is the only parameter changing here and don`t keep gal = "0".

Find the total number of reviews and start from 50 to total pages adding 50 with each request.

```
form_date = {'action':'undefined_Other_ClickNext_REVIEWS_ALL','gaa':'Other_ClickNext_REVIEWS_ALL', 'gal':reviews_till_this_page,'gams':'0','gapu':'Vq8EngoQL3EAAJKgcx4AAAAN','gass':'members'}
```